# Change session value with button click

Tags: html, jsp, session

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="button" value="LOGOUT" onclick='<%session.setAttribute("loggedin","false");'/>
</body>
</html>
```

Need to change session values on a button click. But it isn't helping.  I am trying to avoid the use of forms. Any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

java is server side. a session onject is in your Server memory not in client. you can't change this in client. you most use form

Comment: you most create a servlet and in this any thing you will. im not sure you can do this with write java code in onclick method. what you will not use servlet and form? ofcourse   if your jsp page is index.html you can create a form with `action=index.html?docommand=userof`. then in your jsp check `if (request.getParameter("docommand")!=null && request.getParameter("docommand").equals("userof")) then session.setAttribyte("loggedin","false");`